# Mongo DB connection pooling or connection persistence - Which is better?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it a good practice to have one connection per database if there are more than 10,000 concurrent users. Mongoose driver is used to connect to Mongo DB .
1. How about the performance impact for connection persistence ?
2. Or is it good to use connection pooling if there are more concurrent users ?
3. If 1 connection is used per database , what happens to write operation if connection is being lost ?